# SVN as a backup medium

Tags: svn, backup

On our web server (CentOS) I am setting up a automated daily back-up of our database. Of course I want to send it offsite ( to our office Windows SBS 2003 server ).

Seeing as we already had SVN setup between these two box's I thought I would just SVN COMMIT the backup, until I realized that every commit would be a new revision of this large 800M backup file.

Can I prevent a repo keeping revisions and just overwrite the old revision?

Or am I completely barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Barking up the wrong tree, I think. If your backup set was somehow a plain text file that only experienced incremental changes, it might be workable (though still non-ideal), but Subversion really isn't a backup system. You're better off with a script that copies the file to the remote location, checksums it, and deletes older backup sets in the history.

Comment: I do exactly what you want to do and am very happy. With svn you get infinitely many generations and it stores only the delta of the databases, which is usually very small. If that's not what you want, why not use rsync?

Comment: If you are looking for a flexible backup system, take a look at [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/).